# How do you make svn:externals output into the current directory?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am setting up the following tag structure for our team in SVN (1.7)

```
...\tags\releases
                 \release_1.0
                 \release_1.1
                 \...
                 \latest (points to ...\tags\releases\release_1.1)
```

I am stuck trying to create the `...\tags\releases\latest` tag. I've been trying to set up an `svn:externals` property that doesn't create a sub-directory for the referenced tag. For example, if I do `svn propset svn:externals "somedir ^/tags/releases/release_1.0"`, commit, and then check it out into a `test` directory you get `test\somedir` before you can get to the actual sources.

What is the right way to set up an alias for a tag so that a checkout doesn't create a sub-directory that's not needed?

Comment: Is release_* one-file dir or no? Have you support cross-platform (Windows/*Nix) solution?

Comment: @LazyBadger each of the release_1.0 tags points to the root of a product tree (single dir with a big tree under it). Windows only universe.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of external (because directory-based exernals always create directory at link-point) use OS-specific object for linking: shortcut (will add *.lnk to repo) or Junction Points

Comment: How do you link from one Tag in SVN to another Tag via an OS link?

Comment: AFAIK, Subversion doesn't handle Junction Points or NTFS symlinks.

Comment: @AlG - I use **relative link** inside WC, easy

Comment: @alroc - svn hanen't handle it, only store

Comment: Can you add an example to your answer? I'm not seeing this.